# Error: The request is invalid. Details: A null value was found with the expected type 'search.documentFields[Nullable=False]'

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

After following this doc https://github.com/Azure/azure-search-vector-samples/blob/main/demo-python/code/azure-search-vector-python-sample.ipynb

I created a schema

```
fields = [
    SimpleField(name="id", type="Edm.String", key=True, sortable=True, filterable=True, facetable=True),
    SearchableField(name="text", type="Edm.String"),
    SearchField(name="embedding", type=SearchFieldDataType.Collection(SearchFieldDataType.Single),
                searchable=True, vector_search_dimensions=1536, vector_search_profile_name="myHnswProfile")
```

I am trying to upload documents that are stored in a json format.

> "[{"text":"blah blah","embedding":"[-0.01130323  0.00934206
> -0.01263496 ... -0.02174513 -0.00830184\n -0.0122043 ]"}

When trying to run this command

```
search_client = SearchClient(endpoint=service_endpoint, index_name=index_name, credential=credential)

result = search_client.upload_documents(documents)


print(f"Uploaded {len(documents)} documents")
```

I am running into this issue

Message: The request is invalid. Details: A null value was found with the expected type 'search.documentFields[Nullable=False]'. The expected type 'search.documentFields[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values.

Tried the public doc https://github.com/Azure/azure-search-vector-samples/blob/main/demo-python/code/azure-search-vector-python-sample.ipynb

Comment: Can you update your question with details such as at what part of the sample notebook you are getting the issue, your config details and any other relevant information that can help in reproduce the issue.

Comment: From your sample, your JSON files do not have the key field "id" value and it cannot be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the provided information it seems the "id" field is missing in the sample JSON document you provided, and since it's defined as a key field in the schema, it cannot be null.
To fix this, you can add an "id" field to each JSON document before uploading.
Below is sample code with generating a unique identifier for each document:

```py
# Sample data  
documents = [  
    {  
        "text": "blah blah",  
        "embedding": "[-0.01130323, 0.00934206, -0.01263496, -0.02174513, -0.00830184, -0.0122043]"  
    },  
    {  
        "text": "another text",  
        "embedding": "[-0.01330323, 0.00734206, -0.01163496, -0.01874513, -0.00730184, -0.0102043]"  
    }  
]  
  
  
# Add unique id and convert embeddings to lists of floats  
import uuid  
  
for document in documents:  
    document["id"] = str(uuid.uuid4())  
    document["embedding"] = list(map(float, document["embedding"].strip("[]\n").split(', '))) 
  
# Upload the documents  
search_client = SearchClient(endpoint=service_endpoint, index_name=index_name, credential=credential)  

result = search_client.upload_documents(documents)
```

With above code snippet, I was able to upload the data as per requirement.
[image]